# bin serialization tries to serialize user control which is not part of the object to be serialized

Tags: .net, vb.net, exception, serialization, binary

I have a .net form project which allows users to save a configuration. I have used a binary serialization so far to save the config being hold by an object of a class with many subclasses. It worked fine for weeks, but suddenly it stopped working. I am at it since a day now and cannot find the bug.

The error I get is:
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException"  in mscorlib.dll

It is hard to make a code example here, so I try to explain the details:
There are several usercontrols [like UserControlX] in the project which have references to objects which are part of the object to be serialized [Now OTS]. The OTS, however, does not know any of the usercontrols.

Then the problem occurs, as the additional info in the exception looks like that:
The type "UserControlX" in Assembly ... is not serializable.

Fair enough, but why is the serializer trying to serialize the usercontrol anyway? the OTS does not hold any reference to it, may not know it at all.

The few changes I did yesterday before the problem occured where adding backgroundworkers, both to the UserControlX, but also to the OTS. Also I added a few events in the OTS being caught by UserControlX. I tried to remove all of them but wasn't successful to restore my previous working version. My subversion is too far back ...

This is such an awkward problem and I hope I made myself clear enough. Please let me know if you have any ideas. Please keep in mind that I may not change to xml/json serialization at this time for other reasons.

### solution:

thanks for your comments. i am not a computer scientist and some of the jargon in the comments is a bit unfamiliar. @Vincent saying "events can actually cause problems" made me focus on the events in the project. Again, why making things abstract and bring another level of complexitiy, i try to phrase it, as there is not much to show with code here. all usercontrols have a reference to an object of a shared class 'Session' through "Private WithEvents S As Session" . this shared class (or in this case its instantiation of it through 'S') can catch events  from usercontrols and other objects in the project, often used to communicate with the gui from inside the model. marking all events as nonserializable in "S", which also is not part of the OTS, actually helped. I am very happy, however, do not understand the reason at all. All my events in the whole project are now unserializable (why anyway serialize one).

Comment: thank you. yes I agree, but I would not know to scale down the problem and summarize in a few lines. it is (to me) very big. and the problem is just as i have explained it. maybe i thought it is due to uncaught event, undisclosed bgw or something. maybe there is a way to view the class stack/diagram. it should eventually show up in there if there is a reference.

Comment: @Plutonix : Events cannot be serialized, but the `BinaryFormatter` tries to serialize them unless you apply the `NonSerialized` attribute. So they can actually cause problems.

Comment: @Plutonix : Hmm, odd... I always have to apply the `NonSerialized` attribute to events, otherwise I get an exception.